# Want a oracle schedule expression

Tags: oracle11g

I want to schedule a job in Oracle 11g and run every week on Monday to Friday at 9:00am - 4:00pm every 15 minutes,it should be started immediately and no end date for this job. below is my create statement, I know it is incorrect, but I don't know how to write it in a right way:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'My_job',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'SP_XXX',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=MINUTELY;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI;INTERVAL=15', 
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
```

so, do you know how to write the value for repeat_interval argument?

Comment: Yes, you can check this Calendaring Syntax - 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#BABEJGCH . Other than that I fail to understand the problem here, as you didn't say why the statement is "incorrect".

Comment: Even so, I think you can try this one `repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI; BYMINUTE=15',` and let me know if it works.